# Alternative for loop over all rows pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
d = {
     'jobid': [100, 101,103,104,100,100,101], 
     'memberid': [1,2,3,3,3,2,1],
     'cluster':['bronze','silver','gold','gold','gold','silver','silver']
    }
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
jobid   memberid    cluster
0   100 1   bronze
1   101 2   silver
2   103 3   gold
3   104 3   gold
4   100 3   gold
5   100 2   silver
6   101 1   silver
```

I found the percentage of each cluster for each job with the following code:

```
for i in df['jobid']:
    perc_bronze=round((df.loc[(df['jobid']==i) & (df['cluster']=='bronze')].count()[0]/df.loc[(df['jobid']==i)].count()[0])*100,2)
    df.loc[df['jobid']==i,'BronzeCluster']=perc_bronze
    perc_silver=round((df.loc[(df['jobid']==i) & (df['cluster']=='silver')].count()[0]/df.loc[(df['jobid']==i)].count()[0])*100,2)
    df.loc[df['jobid']==i,'SilverCluster']=perc_silver
    perc_gold=round((df.loc[(df['jobid']==i) & (df['cluster']=='gold')].count()[0]/df.loc[(df['jobid']==i)].count()[0])*100,2)
    df.loc[df['jobid']==i,'GoldCluster']=perc_gold
```

output:

```
    jobid   memberid    cluster BronzeCluster   SilverCluster   GoldCluster
0   100 1   bronze  33.33   33.33   33.33
1   101 2   silver  0.00    100.00  0.00
2   103 3   gold    0.00    0.00    100.00
3   104 3   gold    0.00    0.00    100.00
4   100 3   gold    33.33   33.33   33.33
5   100 2   silver  33.33   33.33   33.33
6   101 1   silver  0.00    100.00  0.00
```

The final result is true but the problem is that it takes a lot of time to run for a large dataset. Is there another way to have this output with lower computational cost?

Comment: Look into [`pd.DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) and [`pd.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html).

Comment: Thanks Jakub. I dont know how to use apply when I have conditions for each cluster and job

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`df.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and use [`GroupBy.value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.value_counts.html) divided by [`GroupBy.count`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count.html), now use [`df.unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html), now merge them using [`df.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with how parameter set to `left`.

```
g = df.groupby('jobid')['cluster']
d = (g.value_counts().div(g.count())
       .mul(100).unstack(fill_value=0)
       .add_prefix('Cluster')
    )
df.merge(d, how='left', left_on='jobid', right_index=True)

   jobid  memberid cluster  Clusterbronze  Clustergold  Clustersilver
0    100         1  bronze      33.333333    33.333333      33.333333
1    101         2  silver       0.000000     0.000000     100.000000
2    103         3    gold       0.000000   100.000000       0.000000
3    104         3    gold       0.000000   100.000000       0.000000
4    100         3    gold      33.333333    33.333333      33.333333
5    100         2  silver      33.333333    33.333333      33.333333
6    101         1  silver       0.000000     0.000000     100.000000
```

Answer (score 3):

This code:

```
unstacked_df = df.groupby(['jobid', 'cluster']).count().unstack()
frequency_df = ((unstacked_df / unstacked_df.sum())*100).fillna(0)
print(frequency_df)
```

Outputs:

```
        memberid                      
cluster   bronze       gold     silver
jobid                                 
100        100.0  33.333333  33.333333
101          0.0   0.000000  66.666667
103          0.0  33.333333   0.000000
104          0.0  33.333333   0.000000
```

Is that the expected behavior?

Comment: Thanks but no. sum of each row for the separate clusters should become equal to one.

Comment: What about that: ```frequency_df = ((unstacked_df.div(unstacked_df.sum(axis=1), axis=0))*100).fillna(0)```